# Proof of boundedness of convergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, solution-verification

### Question

Is the proof below for the boundedness of convergent sequences valid, if a little convoluted? Statement (2) seems to be standing on some shaky ground.

### Proof candidate

Suppose that some sequence $\{z_n\}$ converges to $z$, which means that $|z_n - z| < \varepsilon$ for all $n > N(\varepsilon)$, where $\varepsilon$ is an arbitrary positive real number. Let's call this statement (1).

Suppose, also, that the sequence $\{z_n\}$ is unbounded, which means that $|z_n| > M$ for all $n > N(M)$ for any given $M>0$. This is statement (2).

From statement (1) and the triangle inequality, we have
$$
\varepsilon > |z_n - z| \geq |z_n| - |z|\\
\varepsilon > |z_n| - |z|
$$
and from statement (2) we have $|z_n| - |z| > M - |z|$.

Combining these, we can write
$$
M-|z| < \varepsilon
$$
for all $n>\max\{N(\varepsilon),N(M)\}$. Choosing $M = K|z|$, where $K > 1$, we have
$$
|z|(K - 1) < \varepsilon
$$
which can't possibly be satisfied for any $\varepsilon$, therefore $\{z_n\}$ must be bounded for it to converge to $z$

Comment: This is *not* correct!! Your "assumption 2" means $\lim_{n\to\infty}|z_n|=\infty,$ which is much stronger than unboundedness.

Comment: @AnneBauval which makes my assumptions contradictory from the start?

Comment: Indeed. And this obvious contradiction is of course not what you intended to prove.

Comment: @Kandinskij No, it is not.

Comment: The first statement (this is not an assumption by the way, the assumption is that $(z_n)$ is convergent to $z$, (1) follows from this assumption) is enough. Fix some $N$, all $z_n, n>N$ are inside a ball centered at $z$ of radius $\varepsilon$. You are left with a finite number of terms which can be upper bounded by the maximum one. Done.

Comment: @nicomezi would you mind posting your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your proof has a flaw in the statement (2).

Here is a direct proof :

Let $N$ an integer, since $z_n$ is convergent, there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that $|z_n-z|< \varepsilon$ for all $n>N$.

Therefore, $|z_n|<|z|+\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$ and let $M = \max_{n \in \{1,N\}} |z_n|$.

Finally, for all $n$, $|z_n| < \max(M,|z|+\varepsilon)$, which is finite. Hence, $(z_n)$ is bounded.